# Who first divided the Bible's books into chapters?

Tags: bible, history, church-history

I've heard that the Bible's division into verses was made later than the division into chapters. So, whose translation firstly came up with this system of chapter divisions that we have today?

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapters_and_verses_of_the_Bible#Chapters)?

Comment: Kind of. But the community don't a good post on this issue, so I thought that this question could be helpul to others in the future. Am I wrong?

Comment: I can understand that, and it's hard to believe we don't have one yet. I just don't want it to be marked down as being "too easy" a question.

Comment: Maybe one can elaborate a good and complete answer. Maybe you, if you have time. I'm going to the gathering now, so i can't answer it. But, if you think you can improve the question, be welcome as well, and thanks for the concern. (:

Comment: Felipe: Good question. I recommend, however, that you do a Google search either in your own mother-tongue or in English, using words such as "at what point was the Bible divided into chapters and verses." I'll be a monkey's uncle if that search alone does not give you more than enough material to answer your own question. If so, then you can post an answer to your own question, which is perfectly permissible on this website. Best wishes! Don

Comment: This article will get you started: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapters_and_verses_of_the_Bible. Here's another: http://www.gotquestions.org/divided-Bible-chapters-verses.html. Here's one more: http://www.bibletools.org/index.cfm/fuseaction/Library.sr/CT/BQA/k/179/When-Was-Bible-Divided-Into-Chapters-Verses.htm. Have fun copying and pasting! Don

Comment: @FilipeMerker The question can be made more valuable if you also ask for explanation for [difference numbering in the book of Psalms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalms#Numbering).

Answer (score 1):

The Bible used today by Christians was divided into chapter and verse by Catholic Archbishop Stephen Langton.

Prior to this, the Jewish Rabbis had divided the OT, the OT used in their calendar, so that it could be used in worship through the year.  This was their Catechism and their Liturgy.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

**Old Testament verse divisions**:

Rabbi Isaac Nathan ben Kalonymus, ca 1440 AD, but based on Jewish work going back for centuries.

**New Testament verse divisions**:

Parisian printer Robert Estienne, 1553 AD.

**Chapter Divisions**

As @Marc said already in his answer, Archbishop Stephen Langton divided the Bible into chapters, early 13th century.

Comment: Some more information about the different chapter numbering in Psalms as well as how "extra" verses in Catholic version of Daniel and Esther would be nice.